# Create new rows based on date variable

Tags: r, dataframe

**Problem**

I'm working on data with several variables including a "date" variable. The problem is that i need to have all dates for all couple of variable. 
Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(c("a","a","c","c","c"),c(15,16,0,18,95),c(0,16,0,18,95),c(2017.01,2017.02,2017.01,2017.02,2017.03))
colnames(df) <- c("PL","CDE","LIV","date")
```

I would like to create the row with date  2017.03 as date for the PL a and set the values CDE and LIV to 0.

I gave you here a simplified example but i have multiple values for PL and multiple missing date.
I mean, one PL will have 2017.01 and 201.05 missing but another one will hahe 2017.01, 2017.02, 2017.03.

**What i tried**

I tried to create an `array` "sem" of date from 2013.01 to 2013.53 and 2014.01 to 2014.53, ... 2017.01 to 2017.47 and then i created a `for loop` over the PL variable andin the array "sem" i keep only the date that i don't have for the variable "PL" and i just do a `cbind` of the array "sem" and the variable "PL" so it `duplicates` it itself and then i create the variables "CDE" and "LIV" that i set to 0 and finnaly i do an `rbind`

But this solution takes too long i have over 38 000 variable "PL"

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the OP wants to create a data frame which contains all possible combinations of the weeks from 2013.01 to 2017.47 and the distinct values of `PL`.

This requires to use `expand.grid()` from base R or `CJ()` (*cross join*) from the `data.table` package and to join the result with the exisiting `df`.

```
library(data.table)
# cross join (only 2 years and 5 weeks for demonstration)
mDT <- CJ(yr = 2016:2017, wk = 1:5, PL = unique(df$PL))[
  , date := yr + wk / 100][, !c("yr", "wk")]
# join with df
setDT(df)[mDT, on = .(PL, date)][
  # replace NA by 0 as requested
  is.na(CDE), CDE := 0][is.na(LIV), LIV := 0][]
```

> ```
>     PL CDE LIV    date
>  1:  a   0   0 2016.01
>  2:  c   0   0 2016.01
>  3:  a   0   0 2016.02
>  4:  c   0   0 2016.02
>  5:  a   0   0 2016.03
>  6:  c   0   0 2016.03
>  7:  a   0   0 2016.04
>  8:  c   0   0 2016.04
>  9:  a   0   0 2016.05
> 10:  c   0   0 2016.05
> 11:  a  15   0 2017.01
> 12:  c   0   0 2017.01
> 13:  a  16  16 2017.02
> 14:  c  18  18 2017.02
> 15:  a   0   0 2017.03
> 16:  c  95  95 2017.03
> 17:  a   0   0 2017.04
> 18:  c   0   0 2017.04
> 19:  a   0   0 2017.05
> 20:  c   0   0 2017.05
> ```

The helper table `mDT` looks like:

> ```
>     PL    date
>  1:  a 2016.01
>  2:  c 2016.01
>  3:  a 2016.02
>  4:  c 2016.02
>  5:  a 2016.03
>  6:  c 2016.03
>  7:  a 2016.04
>  8:  c 2016.04
>  9:  a 2016.05
> 10:  c 2016.05
> 11:  a 2017.01
> 12:  c 2017.01
> 13:  a 2017.02
> 14:  c 2017.02
> 15:  a 2017.03
> 16:  c 2017.03
> 17:  a 2017.04
> 18:  c 2017.04
> 19:  a 2017.05
> 20:  c 2017.05
> ```

The full range of values in `mDT` can be created by:

```
mDT <- CJ(yr = 2013:2017, wk = 1:53, PL = unique(df$PL))[
  , date := yr + wk / 100][date <= 2017.47, !c("yr", "wk")]
mDT
```

> ```
>      PL    date
>   1:  a 2013.01
>   2:  c 2013.01
>   3:  a 2013.02
>   4:  c 2013.02
>   5:  a 2013.03
>  ---           
> 514:  c 2017.45
> 515:  a 2017.46
> 516:  c 2017.46
> 517:  a 2017.47
> 518:  c 2017.47
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly why i'm trying to do !!! thank you again

Comment: I have a question, here the only variable i need to expand is PL variable, in my real dataframe, i have combinaison between PL and a variable called Article, do you know how can i insert it in the CJ ?

Comment: You need to include `Article` in the join as well, e.g., `mDT <- CJ(yr = 2013:2017, wk = 1:53, PL = df$PL, Article = df$Article, unique = TRUE)[
  , date := yr + wk / 100][date <= 2017.47, !c("yr", "wk")];
setDT(df)[mDT, on = .(PL, Article, date)][
  is.na(CDE), CDE := 0][is.na(LIV), LIV := 0][]
`

Comment: Does this method create combination that doesn't exist  or it will use only existing combination

Comment: The cross join will create all possible combinations of date x PL x Article based on the exisiting values of PL and Article in df.

Comment: Ahh, i need to create date only on existing combination or Article x PL, because if i create all combination, my file will have over 50 millions rows haha

Comment: I see. So, it should be sufficient to do either date x PL *or* date x Article in the cross join. After the final join, you should get the same number of rows, I believe. (Note that I am allways referring to *unique* values).